# Isomorphism of Graphs (GRE)

Tags: graph-theory

I am using "Cracking the GRE Mathematics Subject Test" by the Princeton Review to study for the test and came across this question about graphs.

> [image]

The answer is (C) and the explanation for why the graph I and the graph II are not isomorphic is the following;

> Although there exists a bijection $f$ such that $f(A)=E$, $f(B)=F$, $f(C)=G$, and $f(D)=H$, adjacencies are not preserved. For example, there is no edge $EF$.

I am new to the subject and am confused. I thought the function that sends the vertex $A$ to $H$, $B$ to $F$, $C$ to $G$, and $D$ to $E$ is bijective and adjacency-preserving. Please explain why this is not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct and the Princeton Review's answer is incorrect. All three graphs are isomorphic, and the pairing $\{(A,H), (B,F), (C,G), (D,E)\}$ does indeed give an isomorphism between the first graph and the second.